# call from xml option tag to java script file

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo-9

I have a code in xml file ie.in optation tag

```
<select id="test">
                      <option value="volvo">Planner</option>
                      <option value="saab">Bays</option>
                      <option value="opel">Drivers</option>
                      <option value="audi">Technitions</option>
</select >
```

and i need to write different functions on clicking of Bays, Drivers and Technitions in java script

Comment: Attach `change` event and apply condition on `Element.value`